# Disable Flutter text Baseline

Tags: flutter, fonts, flutter-layout

How can I disable the textbaseline?

[image]

because my text is not centered

[image]

I try to center a text in a contair. I use this font: https://www.dafont.com/young.font?l[]=10&l[]=1

```
import 'package:flutte_template/styles/theme_dimens.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RoundedChip extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Color color;

  const RoundedChip({@required this.child, @required this.color});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: ThemeDimens.padding4),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Padding(
             padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: ThemeDimens.padding4),
             child: Text('Drama', style: ThemeTextStyles.mediaDetailGenreText),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(999),
        ),
        color: color,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
  static const TextStyle mediaDetailGenreText = TextStyle(color: ThemeColors.textColor, fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500);
```

Comment: did you found the answer?

Comment: Not yet. I think it is a problem with the font itself

Comment: oh, it can be fixed by other fonts?

Answer (score 4):

I hope it helps after this long time :)
wrap the text widget with baseline widget

```
Baseline(
                    baselineType: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                    child: Text(
                      'Some Text',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                    baseline: 40.0,
                  ),
```

Comment: Thanks, i am trying to do this for 10 different languages in 4 different fonts

Answer (score 0):

Just add an inputDecoration with no input border to the textField like this:

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
)
```

Comment: The border is not the problem that is pained by flutter for debugging. (text baselilnes)

Answer (score -1):

Try `TextDecoration.none`, its work for me.
ex: `Text("Hello", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, decoration: TextDecoration.none),)`

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score -2):

I think the issue is on the line height of the Font...
You can tweak that value directly, is in percentage terms of the font size.
So, try the values by eye:
lets say:

```
Text( "Drama", height: 0.8 );
```

Comment: ´height´ can't be set directly on the `Text` widget